How to trigger "Handle error" function in subfunction?
I have some questions about best practices for error handling in bash.
I have created a bash function that I use frequently in my scripts called "handle_error."
At the top of my scripts, I set:
set -e
trap 'handle_error ${LINENO} "${BASH_LINENO[*]}" "${BASH_SOURCE[*]}" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${FUNCNAME[*]:-empty}"' ERR

However, this does not work when creating functions with sub-functions.
So far, the only solution I have found is to repeat these "lines" in every function:
set -e
trap 'handle_error ${LINENO} "${BASH_LINENO[*]}" "${BASH_SOURCE[*]}" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${FUNCNAME[*]:-empty}"' ERR

If I put them in a function, the scope is not correct, and it cannot be repeated by a function. So, I have put these lines in a separate file that I source to make it work.
However, I don't find it very elegant to repeat this in every function where I want to catch errors.
How do you handle this? Do you have a better solution?
my exemple_script.sh


#!/bin/bash

source "catch_error.sh" # should be repeat in each func ?!

function handle_error() {
    local last_exit_code=$?
    local line_number=$1
    local bash_lineno=$2
    local bash_source=$3
    local bash_command=$4
    local func_name=${5:-empty}

    if [ $last_exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "---------------------------"
        echo "An error occurred. Exiting."
        echo "- Function: $func_name"
        echo "- Line: $line_number"
        echo "- File: $bash_source"
        echo "- Command: $bash_command"
        echo "- Exit Code: $last_exit_code"

        # Log the error to a file
        echo "$(date) - Error in function $func_name at line $line_number in file $bash_source: command '$bash_command' exited with status $last_exit_code" >> error.log

        exit $last_exit_code

    fi
}

function function1(){

    ls -lht missingFileForCreateAError_f1

}

function function2(){
    source "catch_error.sh" # Trap commande for start handle_error 


    ls -lht missingFileForCreateAError_f2

}

main(){
    source "catch_error.sh" # Trap commande for start handle_error 

    #function1
    function2

}
main $@`

catch_error.sh :
set -e
trap 'handle_error ${LINENO} "${BASH_LINENO[*]}" "${BASH_SOURCE[*]}" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${FUNCNAME[*]:-empty}"' ERR

Something like that should be enough for trigger handle_error function
function function1(){

    ls -lht missingFileForCreateAError_f1

}


In Bash, you can also export functions.

Where do you have "functions with subfunctions" in your script?

See What does set -o errtrace do in a shell script?.

Also see BashFAQ/105 (Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?).

I don't understand the point about the scope. Traps always are set for the current process, so how is this possibly related to your functions?

Also I find the titel of your question confusing. What is a "subfunction"? This concept does not exist in bash.

"Subfunction" might not be the best term to use, but what can we call a function that is called by another function? If I have a "main" function and within this main function I have a "function1", if I put my trap error lines in the main function, it will work, but not in function1. I have a variable scope issue. But now it’s resolved with the "set -o errtrace" command.

Thanks the line "set -o errtrace" it's works perfectily !
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -o errtrace
trap 'handle_error ${LINENO} "${BASH_LINENO[*]}" "${BASH_SOURCE[*]}" "${BASH_COMMAND}" "${FUNCNAME[*]:-empty}"' ERR

function handle_error() {
    local last_exit_code=$?
    local line_number=$1
    local bash_lineno=$2
    local bash_source=$3
    local bash_command=$4
    local func_name=${5:-empty}

    if [ $last_exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "---------------------------"
        echo "An error occurred. Exiting."
        echo "- Function: $func_name"
        echo "- Line: $line_number"
        echo "- File: $bash_source"
        echo "- Command: $bash_command"
        echo "- Exit Code: $last_exit_code"

        # Log the error to a file
        echo "$(date) - Error in function $func_name at line $line_number in file $bash_source: command '$bash_command' exited with status $last_exit_code" >> error.log

        exit $last_exit_code

    fi
}
function subfunction1(){
    ls -lht missingFileForCreateAError_sub_f1
}

function function1(){
    subfunction1
}



main(){
    function1
}
main $@


Thanks you all for your awsers !
